# Does deleting your Answer to a question delete all the downvotes received?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

I've been posting questions and getting answers. Some of the answerers, if their answer is not acceptable or not good, then after a few moments I find their answer deleted. Does this technique save our points?

Comment: Saves who points?

Comment: Some Users delete their ANSWERS.

Comment: I suppose that you wanted to say `posts` instead of `comments` in the question.

Comment: O god, that's why I was thinking, why all these people are saying about comments, while I'm asking about the answers. sorry my mistake correcting it.

Comment: People who make a habit of doing this will probably find themselves the subject of an answer ban.

Comment: @AlEverett That depends on how often you post a bad answer.  If you delete 100% of your bad answers but only 1% of your answers are bad, you're certainly not going to be answer banned.  If you don't have quality answers to offset your deleted ones, then yes, you could be banned.

Answer (score 4):

If an answer is deleted, all upvote or downvote reputation is restored.

Upvotes on comments do not increase reputation.

Update: As noted [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), posts that have been visible on the site for at least 60 days and have a score ≥ 3 will not decrease reputation if they're deleted. Reason?

> In fast-changing professions, there should be no shame in contributing valuable information just because it eventually goes out of date – and there shouldn’t be a penalty for deleting it when it does. Naturally, editing to bring an answer up-to-date is preferable – but if someone else already posted a good answer with current information, you should be able to remove yours and keep the reward for the time it was useful.

Comment: Its also worth noting that although the rep is returned the question/answer ban is still effected by these deleted posts